How to write SNMP value? Changing printer's DNS
I'm trying to change printer's settings: DNS Server's ipaddress.
In PowerShell it's possible to recieve current value but trying to write it gives error.
PS C:\Users\user> get-module snmp

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.0.1    snmp                                {Get-SnmpData, Invoke-SnmpWalk, Set-SnmpData}
    
PS C:\Users\user> Get-SnmpData -Community 'private' -IP 10.25.59.143 -OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.40.10.1.1.8.1
    
    OID                             Data
    ---                             ----
    .1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.40.10.1.1.8.1 10.25.83.11
    
    
    PS C:\Users\user> Set-SnmpData -IP 10.25.59.143 -Value "10.25.83.12" -Community 'private' -OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.40.10.1.1.8.1 -ValueType IP
    WARNING: SNMP Set error: Exception when calling "Set" with "5" arguments: "error in response"

I've downloaded net-snmp-5.5.1 for Windows command line. The same picture. It's possible to read but writing throws error.
C:\usr\bin>snmpget -v 1 -c private 10.25.59.143 "1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.40.10.1.1.8.1"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1347.40.10.1.1.8.1 = IpAddress: 10.25.83.11

C:\usr\bin>Snmpset -v 1 -c private 10.25.59.143 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.40.10.1.1.8.1 a 10.25.83.12
Error in packet.
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1347.40.10.1.1.8.1

Community value is correct and has permission to write.

I'm doubtful. If the number of devices justifies automation, aren't you using DHCP to provide DNS's ? If not that big, isn't possible to change setting through a web interface ?

Not all objects are writable. Are you able to find the exact MIB document and learn more about this table/objects?

@Civette That is what printer's developers might think ^.^ I'm pretty sure in real word people don't use DHCP on on printers: users turn printers on and off and somehow end up with printer's IP diffrent from what thier computer is trying to print to.

@LexLi Yes, I found out that might be the issue. I'm downloaded another snpmset sofware and it says "error(17) not writtable".

@user2978216. In environments where SNMP is needed, I can ensure you people are using DHCP for printers..... or at least should.
